# Sending base64 string to Server incorrect size

Tags: android, image, base64

I've been trying to upload an image to a webserver using a post request. For easy handling i've changed the image to a base64 string. When I log the base64 string I can see that it's around 4000-5000 characters. But when I receive it on the server I write it to a txt file to see what I get. But the size is over a million characters. Just can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. For some reason the server receives too much information. Is it an issue with the stream or with the filesize? I need to send the full image.

```
    private String encodedImage(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(bytes,0 ,bytes.length ,Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encImage;
}

/**
 * On activity result will launch when activity gives a result back.
 * @param requestCode, code to check for specific request
 * @param resultCode, code to correspond for result
 * @param data, intent that gives back result.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == IMAGE_RESULT_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        // Set the imageview to blank ot fix caching errors
        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);

        //Get file
        File image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "StendeNav/Startpunt.jpeg");
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(image);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // set imageview


        String base64 = encodedImage(bitmap);

        //decode base64 string to image
        byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);

        String urlIn = "http://192.168.43.7/uploadimage.php";
        String urlParameters = "image=" + base64;

        new uploadBase().execute(urlIn,urlParameters);
    }
}
private String httpPOST(String urlIn, String urlParameters, Context context){

    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("");
    byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
    int    postDataLength = postData.length;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlIn);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty( "Charset", "UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
        try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write( postData );
        }

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            data.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        Log.d("Bullshit",e.toString());
    }

    return data.toString();
}

public class uploadBase extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("");
        byte[] postData       = strings[1].getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        int    postDataLength = postData.length;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Charset", "UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
            try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream())) {
                wr.write( postData );
            }

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                data.append(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            Log.d("Bullshit",e.toString());
        }

        return data.toString();        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this function to convert your bitmap

```
public static String convertBitmapToBase64( Bitmap photo) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResult()

```
File file = new File(getPathFromUri(data.getData()));
                path = file.toString();
                Bitmap bm = shrinkImage(path,300,300);
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,outputStream);
                byte[] b = outputStream.toByteArray();
                imageString = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
                imgProfileCircle.setImageBitmap(bm);
                bm.recycle();

private Bitmap shrinkImage(String file, int width, int height) {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

        int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
        int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

        if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
        {
            if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
            {
                bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
            } else {
                bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
            }
        }

        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
        return bitmap;
    }
```